# How to draw those shapes in Metapost

Tags: metapost

I can't figure out how to draw those two shapes in Metapost, are easy but I really don't get it.

[image: two rounded shapes marked by A & B]

This the code I was trying to fix with a [online visualizer](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/):

```
beginfig(0);
draw (0,0)--(5,0)..(7.5,2.5)..(7.5,7.5)..(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle; 
endfig;
```

The sulution was provide by @mickep

```
draw (0,0)--(5,0){right}..{up}(7.5,2.5)--(7.5,7.5){up}..{left}(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle;
```

This perfectly draws `B` how I didn't understand how to revert the coordinates to draw `A`.

Alternatively if you know anything about any tools that can convert simple shape from SVG to Metapost for it would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you show some attempt?

Comment: Inkscape can give you `.tikz`. Why do you want mp especially?

Comment: I am just learning, this is how I am trying: `draw (0,0)--(5,0)..(5,10)..(0,10)--cycle;` It looks like `Inkscape 1.3` doesn't export in `.tikz`, perhaps does it need an extension?

Comment: I improved the drawing: `draw (0,0)--(5,0)..(7.5,2.5)--(7.5,7.5)..(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle;` this doesn't work while this other: `draw (0,0)--(5,0)..(7.5,2.5)..(7.5,7.5)..(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle;` isn't the same shape as `B`... 

Comment: Good, you are close. Try `draw (0,0)--(5,0){right}..{up}(7.5,2.5)--(7.5,7.5){up}..{left}(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle;`.

Comment: @mickep that worked, not sure how you did achieved, as I wrote I am having difficulties to understand, for instance I don't understand how to invert the points to have a like  `A`... 

Comment: `svg2tikz` is what I have installed. I don't know if there are others. It is quite commonly used on this site.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide a proper compilable example? Comments are liable to disappear and no record of any use to others remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we got one correct, the other one is obtained by using `rotatedaround`. I suggest to introduce variables for the points. Also, the `z1{right}` means that we should leave `z1` in the right direction. The `{up}z2` means that we should arrive at `z2` going upwards. I also introduced a unit length `u`, that you can change if you want to scale. Please do not mind the `\startMPpage` and `\stopMPpage`, they are just there to make the example complete for compilation with `context`.

```
\startMPpage[offset=3BP]
u := .25cm ;
z0 = origin ; z1 = (5,0) ; z2 = (7.5,2.5) ; z3 = (7.5,7.5) ; z4 = (5,10) ; z5 = (0,10) ;
z6 = (2,0) ; % shift
path A, B ;
B := z0 -- z1{right} .. {up}z2 -- z3{up} .. {left}z4 -- z5 -- cycle ;
B := B shifted z6 ;
B := B scaled u ;

A := B rotatedaround((0,.5(y0 + y5)) scaled u, 180) ;

fill A withcolor .85white ;
fill B withcolor .85white ;
draw A ;
draw B ;
label("A", (-x6 - .5(x0 + x3), .5(y0 + y5)) scaled u ) ;
label("B", ( x6 + .5(x0 + x3), .5(y0 + y5)) scaled u ) ;
\stopMPpage
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach -- this one is set up for `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

[image: rounded rectangles with A and B labels]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Impact}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  numeric u; u = 12; 

  path C, D;
  C = quartercircle rotated 180 shifted (1/2, 1/2) scaled 2u shifted (-3u, 0) -- (0, 0) -- (0, 5u) --
      quartercircle rotated  90 shifted (1/2,-1/2) scaled 2u shifted (-3u, 5u) -- cycle;

  C := C shifted (-u, 0);
  D = C reflectedabout(up, down);

  fill C withcolor .95; draw C; label("\Huge A", center C);
  fill D withcolor .95; draw D; label("\Huge B", center D);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- With `lualatex` you can control the fonts at the latex level.  Here I am using `fontspec` with the font Impact that is installed on my Mac.
- To make the first "C"-shaped path, I've used the built-in `quartercircle` path, appropriately rotated, shifted, and scaled, so that the corners are circular.
- The "C"-shaped path is then shifted slightly left.  Note that you need to use the assignment operator `:=` to update the variable.
- To get the "D"-shaped path, it is simplest to use `reflectedabout`
- Each path is then filled, drawn, and labelled.